# Count maximum sequel of null values - mdx query

Tags: ssas, mdx

I want to create a member based on this problem

I have a Product A being sold
I want to find the largest range of consecutive days without sale

example:

days 1,2,3 the product not sale, after that,it sold for 15 consecutive days, at 19th day it didnt sell for 2 days and after that it sold every day until the end of the month

so my maximum days without sale was 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query delivers in the Microsoft sample cube Adventure Works what you want:

```
WITH Member Measures.[days without sales] AS
            IIf( [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] > 0
                , 0
                ,(Measures.[days without sales], [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.PrevMember) + 1
               )
     Member Measures.[Max days without sales] AS
            Max( [Date].[Calendar].[Date].Members
                ,Measures.[days without sales]
               )          
SELECT { [Measures].[Max days without sales] }
       ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Adventure Works]
 WHERE [Product].[Product].&[486]
```

The measure `days without sales` is defined recursively, and returns how many days up to and including the current member of the `[Date].[Calendar]` hierarchy there was no sales. You may need to adapt the criteria for "without sale", bearing in mind that in MDX, numerical comparisons treat `NULL` as `0` - which is different from SQL.
This measure only works correctly if there is a member in this hierarchy for each day, i. e. there are no gaps in this hierarchy. And actually, the definition is more general than just working for days: If you use months for the `[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember`, it would give you the number of months without sales, etc. It works with each level of the hierarchy.

The measure `Max days without sales` does not contain the product in its definition, it delivers the maximum days for whatever is in context (in this case the product in the `WHERE` clause).

Please note that - as actually there is a loop over all days in the `[Date].[Calendar]` hierarchy when calculating `Measures.[Max days without sales]`, and within that the recursion again iterates along the previous days, and all this for each cell in the result set - this may be slow for large reports.